# Send WhatsApp Stickers programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp, mssticker

I'm working on an app in Android that needs to open a WhatsApp conversation with a previously chosen sticker.

Maybe is there a way to do it like when a picture is sent, like this:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("image/*");
sendIntent.putExtra("jid", numero + "@s.whatsapp.net");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, filepath);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```